# Manipulating dropdowns populated by AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

JQuery is my best friend in good and bad Javascript times. However, some times it takes some figuring out for me before I finally achieve my goal. This is one of these days. This they I bumped into a certain issue I can't really find my way around. I'll try explaining it below.

#### My HTML

```
<select name="one" id="one">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    ....
</select>
<select name="two" id="two">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    ....
</select>
<select name="three" id="three">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    ....
</select>
```

#### My JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (one != 0) {
        // Set select dropdown one
    }
    if (two != 0) {
        // Set select dropdown two
    }
    if (three != 0) {
        // Set select dropdown three
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '#three', function() {
    var item = $(this).val();
    var url = basePath + 'item/' + item;
    window.location = url;
});
```

#### PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var one = <?= $one; ?>;
    var two = <?= $two; ?>;
    var two = <?= $three; ?>;
</script>
```

#### The issue

What I want to achieve is that when an option is selected in dropdown one, JQuery loads dropdown two. When an option is selected in dropdown two, JQuery loads dropdown three.

I've got this working. However, when dropdown three is selected, it does a refresh. But as soon as that refresh is done, all select values would be set again and another refresh would be triggered.

I want JQuery to only refresh the first time, set all select values after the refresh (thus triggering the change event on the select dropdowns and loading the values) but not refreshing when the third select dropdown value is set.

If I need to do more explaining on this please let me know. Any suggestions and help would be very welcome.

#### Progress

```
if (false !== rootpfgroup && false !== hoofdpfgroup && false !== subpfgroup) {
    $('#one').val(rootpfgroup).trigger('change');
    $('#two').val(hoofdpfgroup).trigger('change');
    $('#three').val(subpfgroup);
}
```

I've found the following to be working. However, it only sets the first dropdown. Selecting a value in the first dropdown triggers an ajax call that loads the options for the second one. Selecting an option in the second drop down triggers an ajax call that loads the options for the third one. Can somebody tell me more on how to go about this and what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, setting the selected dropdown value using PHP to set the HTML `selected` attribute would also work, eliminating your refresh problem and meaning that the value persistence works without JS (whether you care about that is a different matter):

```
<?php
    $one = '';
    $two = '';
    $three = '';

    if (!empty($_POST['one'])) {
        $one = $_POST['one'];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['two'])) {
        $two = $_POST['two'];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['three'])) {
        $three = $_POST['three'];
    }
?>

$(document).on('change', '#three', function() {
    var form = $('#form');
    var item = $(this).val();
    var url = basePath + 'item/' + item;
    form.attr('action', url);
    form.submit();
});

<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <select name="one" id="one">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($one == 1):?>selected<?php endif;?>>One</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($one == 2):?>selected<?php endif;?>>Two</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($one == 3):?>selected<?php endif;?>>Three</option>
    </select>
    <select name="two" id="two">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($two == 1):?>selected<?php endif;?>>One</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($two == 2):?>selected<?php endif;?>>Two</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($two == 3):?>selected<?php endif;?>>Three</option>
    </select>
    <select name="three" id="three">
        <option value="1" <?php if ($three == 1):?>selected<?php endif;?>>One</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($three == 2):?>selected<?php endif;?>>Two</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($three == 3):?>selected<?php endif;?>>Three</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

As I mentioned, depending on what your data actually looks like (assuming it isn't just lists of numbers ;) you might be able to add some loops in your PHP to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$one = '';
$two = '';
$three = '';

if (!empty($_POST['one'])) {
    $one = $_POST['one'];
}
if (!empty($_POST['two'])) {
    $two = $_POST['two'];
}
if (!empty($_POST['three'])) {
    $three = $_POST['three'];
}
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var one = '<?= $one; ?>';
    var two = '<?= $two; ?>';
    var three = '<?= $three; ?>';

    if (one != '') {
        $('#one').val(one);
    }
    if (two != '') {
        $('#two').val(two);
    }
    if (three != '') {
        $('#three').val(three);
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '#three', function() {
    var form = $('#form');
    var item = $(this).val();
    var url = basePath + 'item/' + item;
    form.attr('action', url);
    form.submit();
});

<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <select name="one" id="one">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <select name="two" id="two">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <select name="three" id="three">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This should now set the values as intended.

Comment: I would like the selects to take the previously selected value. For examle, I select One->Two->Four, I would like this values to be selected in the dropdowns after refresh without triggering another refresh.

Comment: Ahh, i misunderstood, will edit my answer in a moment

Comment: This way the dropdowns still wont be set.

Comment: Were on my phone editing, and pressed save too early, but am on a computer now and will fix it, sorry.

Comment: Try out now please :)

Comment: A different approach (which incidentally would degrade better without JS - this may or may not be a priority for you) would be to use PHP to set the values, instead of using PHP to set JS variables:

http://pastebin.com/P4ypwFTU

(you could obviously tidy this up with some loops)

Comment: True, were completely into the code he already made, so i forgot that the js is not even needed. My bad.

Comment: @Djip Oh yes, wasn't a criticism of your answer which equally gets the job done :) Will add mine and OP can choose which direction he wants to take.